# actores que rodaron en una pelicula en español

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema con esta consulta y no puedo resolverla como es debido a causa de que soy nuevo en esto de las base de datos, mi problema es el siguiente: quiero sacar la cantidad de actores que estuvieron en una pelicula en español y listar sus nombres, mi problema radica en que desconozco el numero para poder saber si esta correcto lo que hice.

aqui les dejo los datos:

```
actores (idActor, nombre, apellido) Representa los actores de las películas

idiomas (idIdioma, idioma) Representa todos los idiomas conocidos y que pueden ser utilizados en las películas

peliculas ( idPel i cula , titulo, descripcion, anio, idIdiomaOriginal, duracion, duracionAlquiler, costoAlquiler, costoReemplazo, clasificacion, contenidosExtra)

actoresDePeliculas ( idActor, idPel i cula ) Representa qué actores actúan en cada película.

idiomasDePeliculas ( idPel i cula, idIdioma ) Representa los idiomas en que se encuentra disponible una película
```

Consulta:

````
select concat(upper(a.nombre),'.',upper(a.apellido))as 'nombre completo de actor' from actores as a, idiomas as d, where exists (select * from idiomasdepeliculas as id where d.idIdioma=id.idIdioma and id.ididioma='7' )```
````

Comment: No sé cómo ayudarte si el problema es del enunciado (o de los datos de prueba) y no vemos nada de eso en la pregunta.

Comment: esta seria la letra de lo que debo de hacer "¿Cuáles son los actores que han actuado en todas las películas disponibles en idioma español
(Spanish)? Mostrar el nombre y apellido en mayúsculas en una única columna, con el título
Nombre completo de actor." y creo que para entenderlo mejor seria mostrar el diseño pero no se como podria adjuntarlo aqui con una imagen

Comment: La solución a tu pregunta es que elijas un conjunto de prueba conocido, digamos diez películas de las cuales cinco estén en español, puebles las tablas con sus datos relacionados y luego pruebes la consulta. Luego puedes usar "todas las películas disponibles", lo que sea que eso signifique. La pregunta de cuál será el número, esa no creo que te la resolvamos acá.